# How to declare abstract classes in c++

Tags: c++, oop

Having been taught Java, I am confused by how Object Orientation is implemented in C++.

Having this class:

```
class Car {
    int weight;
public:
    Car(int input) {
        weight = input;
    }
    void sayVroem() {
        std::cout << "Vroem...";
    }
};
```

In Java I would be able to declare this an abstract class by declaring it as `public abstract class Car`. This would result in that the class cannot be instantiated. Is something similar possible in c++?

Comment: Yes. Declare at least 1 member function as purely virtual.

Comment: @nada I am guessing I am doing it incorrectly as I am still able to create an object of type Car if I declare sayVroem() as: virtual void sayVroem().

Comment: as in MikNiller' s answer below; the `=0` part should not be missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this explicitly is to declare all constructors as protected => Then you won't be able to instantiate the class even without pure virtual members.

In your case:

```cpp
class Car {
    int weight;
protected: // only derived classes can access those functions
    Car(int input) {
        weight = input;
    }
    // if you just have the default c-tor you can move it to protected like this:
    Car() = default;
public:
    void sayVroem() {
        std::cout << "Vroem...";
    }
    // feel free to add virtual methods later on if required
};
```

Comment: This does sound like a more clean way. Are there any disadvantages to doing it like this compared to what MikNiller and other suggested?

Comment: I can't think of any disadvantages, you can still add virtual functions later on if you need.

Comment: I guess some code examples of how this technique can be used would be helpful.

Comment: @Evg I do understand what he/she means but you are right. Others might find it helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare at least one method pure virtual, like:

```
class Car {
    int weight;
public:
    Car(int input) {
        weight = input;
    }
    void sayVroem() {
        std::cout << "Vroem...";
    }
    virtual void ImAPureVirtualMethod() = 0;
};
```

If you have no virtual methods

```
class Car {
    int weight;
    public:
        void sayVroem() {
            std::cout << "Vroem...";
        }
   protected: 
      Car () = default;
};
```

Or by making the destructor pure virtual like

```
class Car {
    int weight;
    public:
        Car(int input) {
            weight = input;
        }
        void sayVroem() {
            std::cout << "Vroem...";
        }
        virtual ~Car() = 0;
};
```

One thing to be aware of when using virtual descructors is that when a derived class is destroyed it will call the base class descructor so you will need to provide an implementation, for example:

```
inline Car::~Car() { }
```

There are plenty of stuff out there describing this:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-virtual-functions-and-abstract-classes/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is it common to create a function like that, that has no true meaning in order to make a class abstract?

Comment: Like the `ImAPureVirtualMethod` ? No, that was just to clarify it, normally you would use a pure virtual method that would be overridden in sub classes

Comment: @RuudVerhoef It did not create a function, it declares a function. This simply says: My interface is as described here and will be implemented later. C++ allows to have definitions and only declarations in the same class. There is no additional need for an abstract class.

Comment: @Klaus Thanks. I see Felix Brull just got a downvote. His/her answer made sense to me looking at Java. Could you explain why your method is better (just trying to understand)? My goal is to prevent someone instantiating the class.

Comment: Maybe because you asked about abstract classes, making the constructor protected  also means it cant be instantiated - so if you have no virtual methods you may want to use that method instead.

Comment: @RuudVerhoef: My? Method? I did not gave any answer so there is not my one anywhere.

Comment: I didn't knew about the pure virtual destructor. This seems like the best option because you should declare your destructor virtual anyways when working with derived classes. The problem that occurs when you don't declare your destructors virtual is explaned [here](https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/virtual-destructors.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching online ? 
I'm not using C++ but the research seems pretty easy and with plenty of answers.

[IBM Explanation of C++ abstract classes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/cplr142.htm)

[Wikibooks - C++ Programming/Classes/Abstract Classes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes)

Comment: I did. However I seem to have been trying to use the virtual keyword in an improper way.